# Where can I find and modify the material color attributes in Android Studio as defined by the Material Design Guide?

Tags: android, colors, material-design

Referring to [the following Material design Guide](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation)

I want to modify the 12 different colors in my app e.g. Primary Variant, Secondary, etc.

However, in Android studio, when using the Theme Editor, the list of colors available to modify are different than what is specified in the material design guide. This is true no matter which theme I choose.

The 12 color variants as defined by both the Material Design and in the Theme Editor in android studio are as follows:

Material Design:

```
colorPrimary    
colorPrimaryVariant    
colorSecondary    
colorSecondaryVariant    
colorBackground    
colorError    
colorSurface     
colorOnPrimary  
colorOnSecondary      
colorOnBackground     
colorOnError       
colorOnSurface
```

Theme Editor:

```
colorPrimary    
colorPrimaryDark    
colorAccent    
android:colorBackground     
android:colorForeground     
android:navigationBarColor       
android:statusBarColor    
android:textColorPrimary    
android:textColorPrimaryInverse    
android:textColorSecondary    
android:textColorSecondaryInverse    
android:windowBackground
```

Are these colors just different names for the same thing or am I  just looking in the incorrect place? I couldn't find anything in the material design documentation that that had names similar to what was in android studio so I'm a bit unsure.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure this out in the meantime? Just ran into this after migrating to androidx.

Comment: It seems that currently this is not yet available and the new color scheme is Coming Soon. So at this point, the color scheme is almost the same as with the AppCompat themes.

Comment: @drk Yeah I think you're correct, as I never did figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The new colors attributes are not available on current stable version 1.0.0, however are available in latest 1.1.0 alpha:

`implement "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05"`

The documentation is ahead of implementation. You can check the release logs to have an idea:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases